# Tokens for SQL statement fill in blank instead of NULL making it crash

Tags: sql, sql-server, token, dotnetnuke

I have a sql statement like this:

```
DECLARE @MyVariable as varchar(50)
SET @MyVariable = $(TokenValue)
```

In this the `$(TokenValue)` will fill in a value from a form (ignore how it's doing it, it's not important, just that if there's a value in the field it relates to it'll get filled in there). If The field in the form was left blank however, there will be nothing put there, leaving the end result like this:

```
DECLARE @MyVariable as varchar(50)
SET @MyVariable =
```

rather than

```
DECLARE @MyVariable as varchar(50)
SET @MyVariable = 'FormInputValue'
```

Since there's nothing after the =, how can I account for this and make sure the SQL statement doesn't crash? The token never writes null to it's place, always just a blank if the field was left empty... Any ideas?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Turns out if I put quotations around the token like this: SET @MyVariable = '$(TokenValue)' it works... comes up as an empty string instead of nothing. I think it just has to do with the way these tokens work, they're not all that great.

Comment: Turns out some of the answers did specify that...

Comment: Yes I can see your answer did after I posted the comment. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that you will not be able to bypass this.

This is something that **should** be handed at the application level.

If $(TokenValue) isnot a param, and you do not include the ' in the string value you can try using

```
SET @MyVariable = '$(TokenValue)'
```

This will not work with all var types (INT and FLOAT works, but not decimal)

```
--WORKS
DECLARE @MyVariable as INT
SET @MyVariable = ''
SELECT @MyVariable
--WORKS
DECLARE @MyVariable as FLOAT
SET @MyVariable = ''
SELECT @MyVariable
--DOES NOT WORK
DECLARE @MyVariable as DECIMAL(18,8)
SET @MyVariable = ''
SELECT @MyVariable
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try playing with default parameters e.g

```
create PROCEDURE dbo.test
    @v varchar(50) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    select @v
END
GO
```

and then

```
declare @a table (v varchar(50))

insert into @a
exec dbo.test -- that represents scenario with no token

insert into @a
exec dbo.test 'blah' -- that if there is a token

select * from @a
```

So in your case instead of

```
DECLARE @MyVariable as varchar(50)
SET @MyVariable = $(TokenValue)
```

you would end up with

```
DECLARE @MyVariable as varchar(50)
declare @a table (v varchar(50))
insert into @a
exec dbo.test  $(TokenValue)
select @myVariable = v from @a
```

But that is really hacky solution.
As other suggested it should be rather filtered on the application level

Answer (score 0):

Edited for SQL Server :)  If you write your query like this:

```
set @MyVariable = ''$(TokenValue)''
if @MyVariable = ''''
    set @MyVariable = null
else
    set @MyVariable = substring(@MyVariable,2,len(@MyVariable)-2)
```

If nothing is in the place of `$(TokenValue)`, you get:

```
if '''' = ''''
```

and @MyVariable will be set to `NULL`.  If there is a string in the place of `$(TokenValue)`, you get:

```
if '''teststring''' = ''''
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Because `''` is the way to escape a single quote, each `''` results in one quote in @MyVariable.  Those two quotes are stripped away by the `substring` in the `else` clause.